# LotusScript Function Doesn't Update Field

Tags: function, date, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm trying to get a document to be created for each instance of a string of dates.

This however doesn't work as I'd hoped - the field doesn't update and the debugger doesn't show me anything at all.

Can someone point me in the right direction with my code?

```
Public Sub co_multiDates()

'Basic Error Handler function
'On Error GoTo errorHandler
'errorHandler:  MsgBox("ERROR " & CStr(Err) & ": " & Error$ & " on line " & CStr(Erl))

'Everything below this is designed to populate a field that then populates a column with multiple date values
'This is designed so that when creating a location record for multiple days, there will be multiple entries in the employee's view
Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace       
Dim multiStartDate As NotesDateTime
Dim multiEndDate As NotesDateTime
Dim tempDate As NotesDateTime
Dim dateArray() As NotesDateTime
Dim dateCounter As Integer
Dim AdjustDay As Integer
Dim Source As NotesUIDocument
Set Source = w.CurrentDocument
Dim thisDoc As NotesDocument
Set thisDoc = Source.Document

' populate multiStartDate and multiEndDate with the values from the StartDate and EndDate fields
Set multiStartDate = New NotesDateTime(thisDoc.GetItemValue("StartDate")(0))
Set multiEndDate = New NotesDateTime(thisDoc.GetItemValue("EndDate")(0))

'assign null value to dateCounter   - calculates the difference between StartDate and EndDate
Let dateCounter = 0

While multiStartDate.TimeDifference(multiEndDate) <= 0

    'add to MultiDates
    ReDim Preserve dateArray(0 To dateCounter)
    Set tempDate = New NotesDateTime(multiStartDate.DateOnly)
    Set dateArray(dateCounter) = tempDate

    'add 1 to the date to loop
    Call multiStartDate.AdjustDay(1)
    dateCounter = dateCounter + 1
Wend

'Replaces the value of the MultiDatesArray field in newDoc (current document)  with the value of dateArray
Call thisDoc.ReplaceItemValue("MultiDates", dateArray)

'Updates audit trail field with any changes
Call SetAuditTrail(w.CurrentDocument.document, "auditTrailField", 1,  "PersonName", "Person Name")

End Sub
```

I feel like I am probably missing something very obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you are using UI classes and updating the document, I'm assuming that you are running this code in the Notes client from a document that is open in edit mode, so I tested it in that context by adding the above Sub code to a form with fields StartDate, EndDate and Multidates and called it from the Click event of a button on that form. It added every date between StartDate and EndDate to field Multidates, which seems to be exactly what its intended purpose is.

If you want to create a document for each date in the range, you need to add code within your While loop to do that, such as:

```
' In your declarations...
Dim session as NotesSession
Dim thisDatabase as NotesDatabase
Set thisDatabase=session.CurrentDatabase

' In your loop...
Set newDoc=thisDatabase.CreateDocument
newDoc.Form="ChildForm" ' or whatever 
newDoc.myDate=dateArray(dateCounter)
' Do other stuff to the document, then...
Call newDoc.Save(False, True)
```

If any of my above assumptions are off, edit your question with more details about the context and you will get a better answer.

Comment: You're right rob, I needed to put a loop inside a loop. I needed to use one loop to detect multiple values in a field and then for each of those values, loop through the date array to create a new document for each date. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept or rate up answers that are helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what this function should do : `Call SetAuditTrail(w.CurrentDocument.document, "auditTrailField", 1,  "PersonName", "Person Name")`

But in the rest of the code I do not see any save of the current and/or creation of a new document. `thisDoc.save(false,true)` might help.

I see no reason why the debugger would not run this code.